# Comparing two FASTA files to get the position of the difference using dictionary

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have two files `f1.fasta` and `f2.fasta`. I want to compare sequence in `f1` and `f2`, but also get the position where the nucleotides are different so I can replace them.

Example of `f1` FASTA:

```
>VFG0127

ATGCCTGGAAATATA...

>VFG0007

TTAGGCATATTTCAT...
```

Example of `f2` FASTA:

```
>VFG0127

ATGCCTGGXXXTATA...

>VFG0007

TTAJGCATATSTCAT...
```

I would like to get for example: VFG0127|position 7, X should be A ...

I tried this code but I'm not getting anywhere

```
dict_1 = {}
dict_2 = {}

with open(f1, 'r') as f1, open (f2, 'r') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            id_acc1 = line.strip()
            seq_1 = f1.next().strip()
            dict_1[id_acc1]=seq_1
            #print dict_1
    for line in f2: 
        if line.startswith('>'):
            id_acc2 = line.strip()
            seq_2 = f2.next().strip()
            dict_2[id_acc2]=seq_2
            #print dict_2

    diffkeys = [k for k in dict_1.values()[index] if dict_1[k] != dict_2[k]]
    for k in diffkeys:
        print k, ':', dict_1[k], '->', dict_2[k]
```

I spent hours on this matter and I can't make it work.
Please I am still a beginner, a simple code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please take another look at your input from *"..f1.fasta:"* until *"...I would like"*. It does not make sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. Would depend a bit on how exactly are your fasta files.

```
f1 = open("f1.fasta","r").readlines()
f2 = open("f2.fasta","r").readlines()

## Read the files
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
currentID = ""
for l in f1:
    line = l.strip()
    if line[0] == ">":
        currentID = line[1:]
        dict1[line[1:]] = ""
    else:
        dict1[currentID] = dict1[currentID]+line

currentID = ""

for l in f2:
    line = l.strip()
    if line[0] == ">":
        currentID = line[1:]
        dict2[line[1:]] = ""
    else:
        dict2[currentID] = dict2[currentID]+line

##Assuming that both sequences have same length
for key in dict1.keys():
    if dict1[key] != dict2[key]:
        for i in range(len(dict1[key])):
            if dict1[key][i] != dict2[key][i]:
                print(key, i, dict1[key][i], dict2[key][i])
```

I think your diffkeys is not correct, not sure though. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much